# Sql Query - Generating "lot" numbers on a list for each group of N items with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across a situation where I need to write a query, and I have no clue what the best route is.

So assume I've got data like this:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| EmployeeID |  ProjectStartDate |
+------------+-------------------+
| 1          |  01/01/2017       |
| 1          |  02/02/2017       |
| 1          |  03/03/2017       |
| 1          |  04/04/2017       |
| 1          |  05/05/2017       |
| 1          |  06/06/2017       |
| 1          |  07/07/2017       |
| 2          |  01/01/2017       |
| 2          |  02/02/2017       |
| 2          |  03/03/2017       |
| 2          |  04/04/2017       |
+------------+-------------------+
```

I need to generate project "lots" for each employee, but the lots have a lot number associated with each group of N (let's say 5 here) items. So I need a query that can group by EmployeeID, sort by ProjectStartDate, and then dynamically group each employee's results into groups of 5, assigning an  incremental count to each group. So the end result would be like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| LotNumber  | EmployeeId  | ProjectStartDate |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 1          | 1           | 01/01/2017       |
| 1          | 1           | 02/02/2017       |
| 1          | 1           | 03/03/2017       |
| 1          | 1           | 04/04/2017       |
| 1          | 1           | 05/05/2017       |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 2          | 1           | 06/06/2017       |
| 2          | 1           | 07/07/2017       |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 1          | 2           | 01/01/2017       |
| 1          | 2           | 02/02/2017       |
| 1          | 2           | 03/03/2017       |
| 1          | 2           | 04/04/2017       |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Normally, I'd just create a table for lots, but the lot numbers can change dynamically since they go off of the Date with the first lots generated from the oldest dates. So adding or deleting projects will change every lot number after it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `ROW_NUMBER` and integer division should work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BT ProjectStartDate)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  (RN -1 )/5 + 1 LotNumber,
        EmployeeID,
        ProjectStartDate
FROM CTE
;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple, elegant solution! The query ran over 100,000 records in less than a second!